# How to CloudWatch Laravel logs deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a PHP Laravel Worker deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk & wanted to stream the `/var/app/current/storage/logs/*.log` to **CloudWatch**. However the solutions I came across are either for **Forge** deployments or vanilla **EC2** instances.

Would appreciate any help in this matter.

Answer (score 12):

You need to configure CloudWatch agent as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html):

- Grant IAM Permissions for the CloudWatch Logs Agent;
- Deploy your app zipped together with **.ebextensions/logs.config** file.

I assume that **logs.config** should look like this

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: StreamLogs
    value: true
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: DeleteOnTerminate
    value: false
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: RetentionInDays
    value: 7

packages:
  yum:
    awslogs: []

files:
  "/etc/awslogs/awscli.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [plugins]
      cwlogs = cwlogs
      [default]
      region = `{"Ref":"AWS::Region"}`

  "/etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [general]
      state_file = /var/lib/awslogs/agent-state

  "/etc/awslogs/config/logs.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [/var/app/current/storage/logs]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "var/app/current/storage/logs"]]}`
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/app/current/storage/logs/*.log

commands:
  "01":
    command: chkconfig awslogs on
  "02":
    command: service awslogs restart
```

Please refer to */var/log/awslogs.log* at your ec2 instance for troubleshooting.

Comment: Oficial example file: https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/logs-streamtocloudwatch-linux.config

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this differently using an Amazon Linux 2023 Elastic Beanstalk platform, as their documentation advised using platform hooks rather than .ebextensions

You need to create a LogGroup in CloudWatch and first give your ElasticBeanstalk EC2 service role permissions to write to it.  The default role provided only has permissions to write to LogGroups with the prefix: `/aws/elasticbeanstalk`.  An example LogGroup name for you to create could therefore could be `/aws/elasticbeanstalk/app`.

**.platform/files/app_log.json**

```
{
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
                "collect_list": [
                    {
                        "file_path": "/var/app/current/storage/logs/*.log",
                        "log_group_name": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/app",
                        "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}_current"
                    },
                    {
                        "file_path": "/var/app/staging/storage/logs/*.log",
                        "log_group_name": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/app",
                        "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}_staging"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**.platform/hooks/predeploy/configure-cloudwatch.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
cp .platform/files/app_log.json /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/laravel.json
systemctl restart amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service
```